# Concatenating two IEnumerables with a limit

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, generator

I've been playing around with generators, generics and extension methods in C# (5.0) and wanted to create an extension method for `IEnumerable`, which would append another `IEnumerable` to it and allow a limit to be put on the whole thing.

The way this differs from just using `Concat()` and then `Take()` is that instead of passing an `IEnumerable`, you pass a function that takes an `int` (which represents the amount of elements that are needed at maximum from the second `IEnumerable`) and returns an `IEnumerable`.

Here's what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatLimiting<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> getSecondWithLimit, int limit = int.MaxValue)
    {
        int elems = 0;
        foreach (T elem in first.Take(limit))
        {
            yield return elem;
            elems++;
        }

        foreach (T elem in getSecondWithLimit(limit - elems).Take(limit - elems))
        {
            yield return elem;
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

An example of a use case for this is when you need a limited amount of records from two different databases. You can write something like:

```
return GetEnumerableFromDatabase(someDatabase, 20)
    .ConcatLimiting(limit => GetEnumerableFromDatabase(someOtherDatabase, limit))
    .ToList();
```

---

My concerns:

- Are the two `IEnumerables` going to be handled correctly, assuming that the resulting one is properly disposed of?

  - I have tried out quite a few possible scenarios and it seems to be handled correctly, but I'm not entirely confident.
- Is the name `ConcatLimiting()` not very conform with what you usually see in C#?
- Is this extension method completely useless?

  - Does an easy way to do this already exist?
- Am I more or less following best practices?
- Are there any other glaring issues?

Answer (score 5):

Before answering your questions let me note that your example code is wrong, second parameter should be `Func<int, IEnumerable<T>>` directly `IEnumerable<T>`. If your concern is to do not retrieve unneeded elements from DB you probably need to let this task to Entity Framework (or your favorite ORM), it *understands* `Take()` and generate proper `TOP` clause.

Let me assume, in this example, that you're using EF (and `Users` and `Employees` table have same type...):

```
return dbContext.Users.Concat(dbContext.Employees).Take(20);
```

EF *may* generate something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Users
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Employees
)
```

Now from QP you may verify what effectively will be generated. Almost-optimal expected result (what you're trying to do with your custom method) is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Users
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Employees
)
```

As you can imagine if (2) is ORM generated code (check with your) or ORM generates (1) but you verify QP and you see (2) then simplest proposed code is preferable. ORM will generate best SQL code (for its knowledge) and you will be able to defer query to the last moment (using expressions you can't call custom functions in this way) effectively losing some optimizations it may apply. Note that generated code for, let's say, SQL Server and MySQL may be pretty different (recall rules for *nested* `LIMIT` in MySQL.)

My favorite is still this code (unless you have a measured performance issue):

```
return dbContext.Users.Concat(dbContext.Employees).Take(20);
```

Let's say that you do need your extension method and you can't use proposed code. What should be changed?

- First of all if called function respects its contract (to return at most `limit` items) then you do not need to reinforce this constraint.
- You're not validating your parameters (and if you did you will have trouble because generated `IEnumerable<T>` does it when enumeration effectively happens, that's why so many `*Impl()` method proliferated.)

In code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatLimiting<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
    Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> getSecondWithLimit,
    int limit = int.MaxValue)
{
    if (first == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));

    if (second == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));

    if (limit <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(limit));

    var itemsFromFirst = first.Take(limit);
    return itemsFromFirst.Concat(getSecondWithLimit(itemsFromFirst.Count() - elems);
}
```

Third: I don't like *guard values* like `Int32.MaxValue` even when they're *literally* used. In this case you do not really want to get *only* 2,147,483,647 items but you're using a very big limit to...don't have limits.

Not to mention that *useless* `TOP` clause may slow down your query. See, for example but it's not the only one, [Why SELECT TOP clause could lead to long time cost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9616965/1207195). What I'd do is then to replace `int limit = Int32.MaxValue` with a nullable argument and apply `Take()` only when required.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatLimiting<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
    Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> getSecondWithLimit,
    int? limit = null)
{
    // Arguments validation...

    if (limit == null)
        return first.Concat(getSecondWithLimit(null));

    var itemsFromFirst = first.Take((int)limit);
    return itemsFromFirst.Concat(getSecondWithLimit((int)limit - itemsFromFirst.Count());
}
```

---

For completeness some answers to your questions.

> Are the two IEnumerables going to be handled correctly...

Yes, compiler generated code is correct and it will dispose everything as expected. Note, however, that initialization code won't be executed until you effectively enumerate returned enumeration. This caused some *funny* bugs in code like `File.ReadLines("path_to_file").Take(0)`.

> Is the name ConcatLimiting() not very conform with what you usually see in C#?

It has to be clear, waiting for elevator we may discuss if `ConcatWithLimit()` is better or not...

> Is this Extension Method completely useless?
>   Am I more or less following best practices?
>   Are there any other glaring issues?

Maybe yes, maybe not. See answer...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not too familiar with the C# world and hadn't heard of EF, I'm not sure if it's an option for me, since the database I'm working with is defined by another program, I'll have to read up on ORM's in general it seems.

I thought of making limit nullable but felt like the function having to deal with it being null would be annoying. Come to think of it though, it doesn't need to be optional at all, if the user doesn't want to put on a limit, they should just call Concat.

Comment: I don't see your final version as a viable solution since `Count()` will cause the first `IEnumerable` to get evaluated, which is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @overactor an ORM may be _nice_ to avoid too much SQL code (in one form or another) embedded in your app. I left limit in-place even if an unlimited query may be a separate overloaded function just because it may come from configuration/user interface or be a calculated result. Nullable aren't annoying (to me, of course) and they often simplify your code a lot...

Comment: I know, impact depends on your ORM (SELECT COUNT(*)) but it's better to move it out (fixing)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@Adriano's Repetti great review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142235/59161) your method does exactly the same as if you wrote:

```
return collection1.Concat(collection2).Take(x).ToList();
```

because if `first.Take(limit)` reaches the `limit` then `.Take(limit - elems)` equals zero, so you won't get anything from the second collection. If not, then you get all items from the first one and the rest from the second one so you might as well concatenate both collections in the first place and use a simple linq expression to get as many items as you want.

Also this `getSecondWithLimit(limit - elems).Take(limit - elems)` is the same as `getSecondWithLimit(limit - elems)` because if you take *x* elements then there is no point in *taking* them again with `Take`. You already have the required number of items there.

Comment: Your suggestion is not identical to what I wrote, since the user cannot limit the amount of results to generate for `collection2`, this can impact  performance when the collection can not be fetched lazily. I see what you mean with `.Take(limit - elems)` being superfluous, I put it there as a safe guard as well as to help with the case of `limit - elems` being 0.

Comment: @overactor _everyting_ that works with an `IEnumerable` is lazy so is the [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) extension: _This method is implemented by using deferred execution._ If the _query_ that returns the second collections isn't lazy then it won't by lazy by any magic here.

Comment: I'm aware that you can't make a non lazy collection lazy, the problem is that the second collection might have to be fetched at once. Your way does not allow for that operation to limit the amount of data that is fetched, which was the entire point of the extension method I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps controversially, I'm going to say your extension method does have a purpose given a situation where:

1. <strike>The first collection is already in memory</strike> I can't remember why I thought this applied. I can't think of a reason why now so I'll just strike it off the list.
2. The second collection is not lazy (so `.Take` doesn't help)
3. Fetching the second collection is expensive (so you want to minimise surplus data retrieval)

If all of those conditions are met, I think this is a reasonable extension method. I'd probably change some of the names though.

---

`EnumerableExt` is it really so much effort to type the remaining 7 characters of `Extensions`? Don't abbreviate.

`int elems = 0;`. `elems` is a terrible name. I'd suggest `returnedItemCount`.

`foreach (T elem` - may be a nitpick but I prefer `item` over `element` and definitely over `elem` which is another needless abbreviation.

`getSecondWithLimit` isn't a bad name but it could be better. `getCollectionWithMaximumCount` is a bit of a mouthful but it's unambiguous.

I'd remove the default value on `limit` and rename it to `maximumItemCount`. I'd also verify that it's greater than 0 and throw an exception if it wasn't.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AppendUpToMaximum<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, 
        Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> getCollectionWithMaximumCount, 
        int maximumItemCount)
{
```

Comment: Could you tell me what your reasoning is behind `collection1` having to be already in memory? As far as I can tell, that should make no difference. Your naming suggestions are good, especially `elems` is a terrible name in hindsight. I'll stick with starting the methodname with Concat to stay in line with the Linq method though.

Comment: I'll also stick with `first` and `second` because those are used in Concat.

Comment: @overactor - I can't remember why I thought it was more appropriate when the first collection was already materialised. I'll have a think and update. Concatenate literally means join together - as you're only joining to a subset of the second thing it doesn't seem quite right to me but it's hardly a massive issue.